# Different settings of Spring contract testing per environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-contract

I have some consumer contract tests that should run on Jenkins on offline mode because the producer and the consumer APIs use both the same local Maven repository on the server, and the tests would crash if they tried to download the stubs of the producer as they are already locally. However on local they should be disabled or run on online mode as the producer API is quite stable and the interfaces rarely change.

I have prepared a workaround but there may be better ways of doing it. My solution is:

1) Configure the tests of the consumer to run with workOffline = true

2) Add this code to the test class so the contract tests are disabled if the system property "runContractTests" is not set:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void checkContractTestsAreEnabled() throws IOException {

    boolean runContractTests = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("runContractTests"));
    assumeTrue(runContractTests);
}
```

3) Run the tests like this on Jenkins:

```
mvn clean verify -DrunContractTests=true
```

Any suggestions of better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify surefire to only run the contract tests in a certain profile. You can also use classpath scanning to get stubs from classpath. You can also enable / disable the plugin on certain conditions (system props / env props / etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I have just added it as an answer as I cannot add the code formatted in a reply to your answer.

Comment: Cool! Glad that you've managed to male it work in an easy way

Answer (score 1):

This solution is more standard. I have added a Maven profile so the contract tests are only executed when the Maven commands are executed with "-P runContractTests".

I have used the suffix CT for the contract tests. Apart from this I have added the suffixes of the other types of tests of the project so they are also executed. In my case *Spec for the Spock integration tests and *Test for the unit ones.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>runContractTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*CT.*</include>
                            <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                            <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```